# Android google api + database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I'm currently writing an application for my friends.
I'm using google places API to get all of the restaurants nearby. 
Its an Async request, BUT i'd like to do a SQL select for all of these restaurants. ( its a simple mysql db).
But as I read on the internet, these selects must be async too.
Could you please help me with this?

EDIT:
 pastebin.com/wh1uktRD

Comment: What have you tried so far? share some code?

Comment: Sure, sorry. https://pastebin.com/wh1uktRD I realized, it wont work, cause thats async.